# Writing .xlsx file to disk and reading into a byte array results in error when attempting to open the file

Tags: excel, vb.net, mime-types

Using VB.NET, we write a .xlsx (Excel Workbook) file to disk and then read into a byte array. Opening the Excel Workbook using File Explorer works correctly, but writing the byte array to the Response output stream and opening the downloaded file in any browser gives an error message (see below).

This error does not occur on regular Excel (.xls) files.

> Microsoft Excel: We found a problem with some content in 'xxx.xlsx'. Do you want us to recover as much as we can?

```
Dim tB As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(diskOpts.DiskFileName) 
Response.Clear() 
Response.Buffer = True 
Response.ContentType = sUtilities.Instance.GetMimeType(tExtens) 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" & fRep.Name & "." & tExtens)
Response.OutputStream.Write(tB, 0, tB.Length) `
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an ASPX page to send the file; if that is the case, you should use an [ASHX handler](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) instead.

Comment: This works with all mime types except Excel Workbook. We use the same process with regular Excel (.xls) without any problem.

Comment: Have you used a hex editor to compare the original file with the faulty downloaded file to see what is different?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it like this?

```
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.WriteFile(fileName)
```

**EDIT**

I looked at our website that allows users to download a variety of files.  This code works for .xslx files.

```
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(docPath)
                Response.Clear()
                Response.ClearHeaders()
                Response.ClearContent()
                Dim ext As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(docPath).ToLower
                If ext = ".pdf" Then
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                Else
                    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
                End If
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & IO.Path.GetFileName(docPath))
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString())
                Response.BufferOutput = True
                Response.TransmitFile(docPath)
                Response.End()
```

Comment: Or even `Response.TransmitFile(filename)` instead of the WriteFile—it hands the work over to IIS. [TransmitFile(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile?view=netframework-4.8.1): "Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream, without buffering it in memory."

Comment: Same issue. We get an error when trying open the file in Excel. Again, this whole process works when writing a .xls file.

Comment: @ITM - see edit above.  Andrew had a good point and years ago I must have came to the same conclusion.